# iOs: Error while cancelling performrequest

Tags: ios, request, nsthread

In my iOs SpriteKit application, I play voice overs using the AVAudioPlayer after a certain amount of seconds after a user action, like so:

```
[self.vOSoundManager performSelector:@selector(playVoiceOverWithName:) withObject:@"Voiceover_waarhondenbrokken3" afterDelay:8.0];
[self.vOSoundManager setRequestBeingPerformed:TRUE];
```

When a user performs another action, the sound should stop playing. I do this like so:

```
if(self.vOSoundManager.requestBeingPerformed){
            [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self.vOSoundManager];
            [self.vOSoundManager stopCurrentSound];
        }
```

The stopCurrentSound method in VoiceOverSoundManager:

```
- (void)stopCurrentSound{
self.playing = FALSE;
[self.voiceOverPlayer stop];
self.voiceOverPlayer = nil;
}
```

When the cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget method is called, I get the following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[VoiceOverSoundManager name]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x155a9590'
```

I have no idea why. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Is there some other instance of AVAudioPlayer in your code or self.voiceOverPlayer is the only player you use to play all sounds?

Comment: I use other instances of VoiceOverSoundManager (which uses the AVAudioPlayer), but I implemented them to try to solve this problem. So before those were implemented, the problem was also there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using one instance of player to play all sounds in your game, this could be a problem if you don't re-create it after stopCurrentSound method is executed:

```
self.voiceOverPlayer = nil;
```

Try to remove this line or create a new player instance.

Comment: I removed the line from VoiceOverSoundManager, but it still throws the error.

Comment: Also, I have this line in my VoiceOverSoundManager:

    self.voiceOverPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:self.voiceOverURL error:&error];

If I turn on breakpoints, it always stops there, even when I didn't put a breakpoint there myself.